# Java Transformer setOutputProperty()

Tags: java, xml, apache, xslt, transformer-model

I am currently using the following code to indent XML:

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
```

This indents the code perfectly well however, I am not sure what the `http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount"` is doing. The URL is essential for the indentation. Could someone explain what this URL does and how it works?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding default property `indent-amount` which is defined in `org.apache.xml.serializer` package. This enables indentation (since default is 0).

> Output properties for XML, HTML, and text transformation output are defined in property files in the org.apache.xml.serializer
>   package.
>
> You can override the default value of these properties in your
>   stylesheet by using the attributes of an xsl:output element. You can
>   override the Xalan specific default settings as follows:
>
> Declare the xalan namespace in your stylesheet element
>   (xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan").
>
> Use the namespace prefix you assign (for example, "xalan") to redefine
>   properties of interest in the stylesheet xsl:output element (for
>   example, xalan:indent-amount="5"). The following stylesheet fragment
>   declares the xalan namespace and sets indent-amount to 2:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
>                 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>                 xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan">
>
>   <xsl:output method="xml" 
>               encoding="UTF-8"
>               indent="yes" 
>               xalan:indent-amount="2"/>
> ```

You can find more at http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/usagepatterns.html under chapter `Configuring serialization output properties`.

**All this assuming your serializer is xalan specific**